# In Groovy: Installing a .msi silently with powershell as admin

Tags: powershell, groovy, windows-installer, silent

I am writing a script for software that runs scripts on remote machines to install packages. this time that package is a .msi.

I have some basic code that does what I want, however only if the cmd that started the groovy was started as admin:

```
package test;

public class test{

/**
 * 
 */
public static main(String[] args){
    def proc = "powershell.exe -command msiexec.exe /i D:\\path\\test.msi /QN /L*V \"C:\\Temp\\msilog.log\""
    
    def test = proc.execute();
    test.waitFor()
    println test
}
```

}

I tried starting an elevated powershell:

```
def proc = "powershell.exe -command Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList `msiexec.exe /x D:\\path\\test.msi /QN /L*V \"C:\\Temp\\msilog.log\"`"
```

but it returns the error java.lang.ProcessImpl@74ea2410.

Obviously there is something wrong there, but I can't find it. Another problem is that when I for example run:

```
def proc = "powershell.exe -command Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList `ls`"
```

It asks me if I want to let powershell make changes to my system, which defeats the purpose of it being silent.

Any ideas?

Comment: just a thought: why do you need powershell to start msiexec? why not directly start msiexec.

Comment: for security reasons you can't have elevated permissions without interaction if you don't already have elevated somewhere else.

Comment: Hadn't thought of starting msiexec directly as an option to be honest.
Makes sense about elevation, I kind of expected as much. I would still like to know how to correct the command for it to go through, but I think fully silently is not possible here.

Comment: Depending on the application you might replace the installer with manual install options if you can use another system as a Templates. So do like copy files, set permissions, modify default config, with a GPO and/or script

Comment: Regarding the correct silence parameter i would not waste much time. If you bought it then it has to work. If it does not, got to the reseller/vendor and tell them to fix it or give you the information.

Comment: Try to enclose your PowerShell code with { curly parentheses } :
`powershell.exe -command "&{Start-Process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList "/i D:\path\test.msi /QN /L*V C:\Temp\msilog.log"}"`